# how can i show a loading message MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I´m making a website in MVC 3, when i click on "submit button", the method will load a page with data from database, which can take a long time...I would like to display a message "loading ", so that the user knows that there is no problem, it´s only loading the data...

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">

    <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Load

</button>
```

Could you help me??

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with MVC meaning it can be done with simple javascript/jquery.

Assuming you are using JQuery you can do something like:

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#mySubmitNutton").click(function() {
       $(".classNameOfYourLoader").show();
     } 
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you in advance!! I dont know javascript and jquery... so if you could be more specific...

Comment: You need to add the lines of code I posted above to your view which contains the form that you're submitting. Additionally you need to add a script reference for the latest jquery library. this should already be the case if you created a new MVC 3 template project in Visual Studio. In any case, read up on jquery and javascript as any modern web app development without those two is a waste of time.